# projection on a hyperplane

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Projection of origin on a hyperplane defined by $a^Tx + b = 0$, as given [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_vecs_hyp.html) is $ab$.  But when I workout, it is $a\lvert b \lvert$. (distance from the origin to $a^Tx + b = 0$, is $\lvert b \lvert$ (assuming $a$ to be a unit vector). Hence the vector is $a\lvert b \lvert$.

Also, the way they come up with solution is not straightforward. Anyone can explian to me ?.  Also, is there a closed form for the projection of a vector $y$ on a hyperplane (other than $a\lvert a^Ty + b \lvert$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you have normalized so $a^Ta=1$. There are different ways to view orthogonal projections. One is through a parameter saying that $a$ is normal to your plane so the projection of the origin should be $ta$ for some real $t$. Inserting in the equation for the plane yields $t(a^T a)+b=t+b=0$ so $t=-b$ and the vector is $-b a$. Taking more generally a vector $y$ the projected vector should be $ta+y$ (again for some $t$) and then $a^T (ta + y)+b=t+a^T y+b=0$ from which you get the result $y-a(a^T y+b)$. Does this clarify?

Comment: why the projection of $y$ is of the form $ta+y$ ?.  $a$ is orthogonal to the plane, so it should like in the origin case right ?. Why we add $y$ ?

Comment: Perhaps better to introduce points rather than vectors? Let $y$ be the vector from the origin to a point $Q$. We project the point $Q$ orthogonally to a (unique) point $P$ in the plane so that the vector $QP$ is orthogonal to the plane. But this means that $QP=ta$ for some $t$ and since $Q$ has the same coordinates as $y$, $P$ will have coordinates $y+ta$. A drawing would probably help.